# How to control the batch-size when using MyBatis ExecutorType.Batch for batch insert operations

Tags: bulkinsert, ibatis, batch-processing, mybatis, batch-insert

I am trying to use mybatis batch execution (ExecutorType.BATCH) support. I want to batch insert few records in database performance and scalability reason. I want to override the default Mybatis batch size. I did not found any way to configure batch-size programmatically. Is there a way to override the default batch-size? The following is the code for your reference:

```
public static void BatchUsingMyBatis() throws Exception
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setname("someone");
        contact.setphone("somephone");
        contact.setemail("someone@somedomain.com");

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeanConfiguration.xml");

        SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = appContext.getBean(org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.class);
        SqlSessionFactory factory = factoryBean.getObject();
        SqlSession session = factory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false);

        session.insert ("ins", contact);
        session.insert ("ins", contact);
        session.insert ("ins", contact);
        session.insert ("ins", contact);
        session.insert ("ins", contact);

        session.commit();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may find that [this](https://pretius.com/blog/mybatis-batch-update-insert-delete/) may help. In short, he suggests using the ibatis `@Flush` annotation in your Batch Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly and you would like to be able to configure session so that one commit would generate multiple batch inserts. For instance if there would be possibility to set that maximum of thee statements were sent at once, code that you supplied would generate one batch insert(three rows at once) and another batch insert(two rows at once). 
I couldn't find information about such functionality and I believe there is no such functionality, but to implement this behavior you would need to override BatchExecutor doUpdate method and Configuration newExecutor method so that it would be aware of new Executor class.